# Stop OpenOffice Writer from adding trailing cents after dollar sign

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

Whenever I precede a number with a dollar sign in a table in OpenOffice.org Writer, the autocorrect forces **.00** on the end of the number.

How do I turn this auto-correct off?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Tools | Options | OpenOffice Writer
Table -> Input in Tables

Turn off "Number Recognition"